# Pin Image and Text show blur and not set properly then how to do show clearly. please give me solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

[image]

**Calling methods**

```
UIImage *imgmarkericon = [self finalimg:[markerInfo valueForKey:@"assets_name"] img:[self mergeImg:pinImage str:[markerInfo valueForKey:@"assets_name"]]];

 marker.icon = imgmarkericon;
```

**Merge Pin image and label**

```
-(UIImage*)mergeImg:(UIImage*)img str:(NSString*)txt
{

    UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgMarker1.png"]; //it's a pin image 
    UIImage *image = img; //pin image

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(30,50);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width-10,newSize.height-10)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(4,5,12,15) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

**Lable text set on image label text background image white color**

```
-(UIImage*)finalimg:(NSString*)txt img:(UIImage*)img
{
    UIImage *imageblank = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"markerlbl.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];

    UIImage *image2 = [self drawText:txt inImage:imageblank atPoint:CGPointMake(0,3.5)];
    UIImage *image1 = img;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width+50, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,40, image1.size.height)];

    [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,40,imageblank.size.width-3,imageblank.size.height)];

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;

}
```

**Draw text to image**

```
-(UIImage*)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image1  atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image1.size);

    //[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image1.size.width,image1.size.height)];
    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,image1.size.height)];
    //CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x+5,point.y-4, image1.size.width+20, image1.size.height+20);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x+5,point.y-4, image1.size.width, image1.size.height+20);


    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

in this code not show clear pin image and text, i need a clear text and image please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Google Static Maps API`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro), Static Maps API lets you embed a Google Maps image on your web page without requiring JavaScript or any dynamic page loading. The Google Static Maps API service creates your map based on URL parameters sent through a standard HTTP request and returns the map as an image you can display on your web page.

Sample URL Parameters:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?parameters

- `scale` affects the number of pixels that are returned. scale=2 returns twice as many pixels as scale=1 while retaining the same coverage area and level of detail. This is useful when developing for high-resolution displays, or when generating a map for printing. The default value is 1. Accepted values are 2 and 4 (4 is only available to Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers.) See [Scale Values](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#scale_values) for more information.
- `size` defines the rectangular dimensions of the map image. This parameter takes a string of the form {horizontal_value}x{vertical_value}. For example, 500x400 defines a map 500 pixels wide by 400 pixels high. Maps smaller than 180 pixels in width will display a reduced-size Google logo. This parameter is affected by the scale parameter.

**Note**:
To support high resolution screens by specifying separate images for each resolution. The scale parameter makes it easy to request a map image for a standard resolution screen, and the matching map for a high resolution screen, simply by setting scale=1 and scale=2 respectively.